# read a csv file with missing values and bonded column

Tags: r, csv

I have to read a csv file of this form:

[image: NOAA data of 8 days]

I've tried with `read.demand`

and

```
NOAA <- read.demand("C:/Users/.../NOAAdata.csv")
```

but I receive this following message after trying to read it:

```
"more columns than column names"
```

As you can see, on the last row, I have 0.00T***** which makes R believes that there is just one column.

I've also tried with `read.fwf` but nothing interesting has showed

Does someone know how to read this kind of file with this type of data??

Note that those data come from the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration and are protected by copyright

thank you for your answer

Comment: Have you tried `read.csv` ? (type `?read.csv` in the console for help)

Comment: Additionally, `more columns than column names` indicates that your data might have row names or a column that does not have a name (e.g. the header has 10 values, but the data is contained within 11 columns)

Comment: Can you post the text file you are trying to read in? NOAA data is in the public domain as it is generated by government employees in the course of their duties are government employees. You should be able to link us to the original course or post a sample of the file you are trying to read in. Sometimes there are odd characters that create the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with read.csv but the "more columns than column names" comes from the last line on my post, the "T" is bonded with the next column.

Here is the file:
http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/orders/7465786967085dat.txt

I had a copyright message when i uploaded it, weird